$\left\{ (x_{1},x_{2}) \in [0,1]^{2}: \exists h \in S,x_{i} = \int h \, d\mu_{i} , i=1,2 \right\} $ compact?

Given probability measure $\mu_{1}$ and $\mu_{2}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and assume they both have density. Let $S$ be the measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, that takes value in $[0,1]$. Is the following set compact?
$$
\left\{  (x_{1},x_{2}) \in [0,1]^{2}: \exists h \in S,x_{i} = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} h \, d\mu_{i} , i=1,2 \right\}
$$

I tried showing the limit of every sequence that exists, but I cannot construct a $h$ that achieves the limit. Also tried all the basic switching limits and integral theorems, but here we don't know if $h^{(n)}$ converges pointwise.
This problem is motivated in applications where we need to optimizing over this set.

I do not understand the close votes. All the convergence theorems for the Lebesgue integral fail, as a sequence $(h_n)$ in $S$ may not have a pointwise converging subsequence. There is your context.

Here is a proof: the set $S$ is a closed subset of the unit ball of $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$, where $\mathbb R^n$ is supplied with the Lebesgue measure. By Banach-Alaoglu, this unit ball is weak-star compact.
Also $S$ is closed in the weak-star topology as can be seen from
$$
\{ h \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n): \ h \ge0\}=
 \{h \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n): \ \int_{\mathbb R^n} hs\ dx \ge0 \quad \forall s \in L^1(\mathbb R^n) : s\ge0\}\\
= \bigcap_{s \in L^1(\mathbb R^n) : s\ge0} \{ h \in L^\infty(\mathbb R^n): \ \int_{\mathbb R^n} hs\ dx \ge0\},
$$
(where $dx$ means integration against Lebesgue measure).
Since the measures $\mu_i$ have densities $w_i$, we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} h \ d\mu_i = \int_{\mathbb R^n} h w_i \ dx,
$$
so that $h \mapsto (\int_{\mathbb R^n} h \ d\mu_1,\int_{\mathbb R^n} h \ d\mu_2)$ is continuous from $L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with the weak-star topology to $\mathbb R^2$.
Then the set under question is the image of the weak-star compact set $S$ under a weak-star continuous map, hence it is closed.
(If you do not like to work with weak-star topologies, you can also argue with sequences: the set $S$ is also weak-star sequentially compact, so that a sequence $(h_n)$ of elements of $S$ has a weak-star converging subsequence.)

A repackaging:  one can use Lyapunov's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure#Lyapunov's_theorem) about vector measures:  $A\mapsto \int_A (w_1(x),w_2(x) dx$ is a continuous vector measure (on $\mathbb R^n$) , so its range is closed.  Integrability of $w_1$ and $w_2$ yields boundedness.

Thanks for the comment. I missed the closedness in the Lyapunov theorem. Iirc Rudin proves that theorem using weak-star topology on $L^\infty$.

Yes, as do Diestel and Uhl.  But Bogachev vol 2 gives a proof that does not.
